# Difference between Command Processor and Shell

Tags: shell

What I know is that a *Command Processor* is a system program that accepts instructions from a *Command Line* or *Terminal* and executes them. Additionally, *Shell* program is a command interpreter so in Unix like systems shells are like (zsh, sh, bash, ...).
I just want to know if shell is a type of command processors and if not what is the classification of it ?

I want to understand in a bit detail.

Answer (score 1):

Shells are not only in Unix. Have you heard of an "expert system shell"?

Windows has a shell. No, not PowerShell (that too), but the Explorer is also referred to as the Windows Shell. It has an API, which lives in the `shellapi.dll`, which has functions like `ShellExecuteEx`. So that is a graphical shell, in which you execute graphical commands (e.g. clicking on something to open it, or dragging from one folder to another) rather than textual command lines.

"Shell" means, roughly speaking, the user-facing layer: user interface. I think that it particularly refers to a situation in which the system has other interfaces, like programming interfaces. The shell is a separate program which is uses those interfaces, and which could, in principle, be replaced by another one.

So, probably, we wouldn't refer to, say, the command interpreter in a boot-loader like U-Boot as a shell; it's not a separate program written to a middleware API exposed by U-Boot. As another example, the command processor inside a modem which accepts `AT` commands isn't referred to as a shell, either.